# namespace in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

what is the use of using declaration type of namespacing over using directive type of namespacing??when to use each one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration type of namespace directive introduces selected named symbols into your <s>code</s> scope (and leaves other symbols from the same namespace inaccessible without the namespace qualifier).

The using type of namespace directive introduces all symbols from the namespace into your <s>code</s> scope - which means you don't necessarily know exactly which symbols were introduced (there could have been undocumented symbols, or symbols left over from previous versions of the library, or ...).

- For control, use the declaration type of namespace directive.
- For convenience (with risk), use the using type of namespace directive.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the using declaration allowing access to a symbol rather than a namespace, the using declaration also brings the symbol to the scope of the declaration. The using directive only affects lookup.

Comment: It also adjusts access qualification.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan already resumed the differences between `using namespace foo;` and `using foo::Bar;` but I think his answer is unfortunately incomplete.

First: `using namespace` should never appear in a header file. By doing so you might render it impossible to use in combination with other header files because of a symbol clash...

Second: in general, you should try to limit the scope of the symbols as much as possible, you probably already do it while writing code:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
  std::string myString = myVec.at(i);
  if (myString == "Foo") { std::cout << "Found"; break; }
}
```

Here it would be useless (and polluting) to have `myString` declared outside the `for` loop. In fact, that very advice can be found in a number of books:

From Scott Meyers' [Effective C++](http://www.amazon.fr/Effective-Specific-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/0321334876), Item 26: **Postpone variable definitions as long as possible**.

From Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu's [C++ Coding Standard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586), Item 18: **Declare variables as locally as possible**

There is no reason not to do the same with `using` declarations.

Third: consider alternatives to `using`: namespace aliasing and `typedef`.

```
// foo.h

class Foo
{
public:

  std::vector<std::string> getSynonyms(const std::string& s) const;

private:
  typedef std::map< std::string, std::vector<std::string> > synonyms_type;
  synonyms_type mSynonyms;
};

// foo.cpp (never in header, at general scope)

namespace fu = boost::fusion;

std::vector<std::string> Foo::getSynonyms(const std::string& s) const
{
  synonyms_type::const_iterator it =
    std::find(mSynonyms.begin(), mSynonyms.end(), s);

  std::vector<std::string> result;
  if (it != mSynonyms.end()) { result = it->second; }

  return result;
}
```

What are the advantages ?

- namespace aliasing > reduce typing almost as much without injecting the types right in the current scope so without risk
- typedef > reduce typing more than `using` and allow easy change of underlying type too.